# Factorize the polynomial $f(x)=4x^2-4x+8$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Factorize the polynomial $f(x)=4x^2-4x+8$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$

*My approach*

First we consider in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
Let $$f(x)=4x^2-4x+8=2*2*(x^2-x+2)$$ I claim that $2$ and $(x^2-x+2)$ are ireducible,the fisrt is irreduzible since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD and PID and then the primes numbers are the irreducible factors, the second comes from , since  the discriminant is $\Delta<0$ and $(x^2-x+2)$ have degree $2$ then have two complex roots and therefore are irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ therefore since $\mathbb{Z}[x]\subset \mathbb{R}[x]$ then $(x^2-x+2)$ is irreducible and therefore:
$$f(x)=2*2*(x^2-x+2)$$

For the second case in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the same argue since  $\mathbb{Q}[x] \subset  \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\Delta<0$ implies that $(x^2-x+2)$ is irreducible in  $\mathbb{Q}[x]$  and therefore
$$f(x)=2*2*(x^2-x+2)$$

In the thrid case in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$ notice that there exists $c_1=\overline{5}$ and $c_2=\overline{7}$ such that $f(c_1)=f(c_2)=0$ and that implies that $c_1,c_2$ are roots of the polynomial and therefore
$$(x)=2*2*(x^2-x+2)=2*2*(x-5)(x-7)$$ and note that
$$(x-5)(x-7)=x^2-12x+35=x^2+10x+2=x^2-x+2$$
Is my  approach right?

Someone can give me an other prove of the fact that $x^2-x+1$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Comment: Consider the rational roots theorem

Comment: It is true that [tex](x- 5)(x- 7)= x^2- 12x+ 35[tex] and that is, modulo 11, [tex]x^2+ 10x+ 2[/tex].  Further, -1 is equivalent to 10 (mod 11)  but how did that "2" become "1"?  Was that a typo and you meant [tex]x^2- x+ 2[/tex]?

Comment: Thanks these are a error

Comment: Why mi question had a $-1$, I relly make an effort to write it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tittle question has the following answer. First, $f(x)=4(x+6)(x+4)$ is the factorisation over the finite field $\Bbb F_{11}$, as you said. Secondly, $x^2-x+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), and as a monic polynomial then also over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks so much, but you can tell me what means $\mathbb{F_{11}}$

Comment: @BrienNavarro:  $\mathbb F_{11}$ is the field with $11$ elements ($\mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z$)